# Javascript toggle multiple div one by one by clicking same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this code in my form, and I want to toggle each divs one by one by clicking the same button repeatedly. But when I click the button, everything shows up, is there a way to toggle it one by one by clicking the same button?

```
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
    <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 2:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment2" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
    <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 3:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment3" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
    <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 4:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment4" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
    <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 5:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment5" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
```

Here's the button that toggles it;

```
<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggler(\'msg2\');">New Message</a>
```

The javascript code for toggling it;

```
function toggler(divId) {
    $('#' + divId).toggle();
}
```

I'm just a beginner with js and I want to toggle the inputs one by one by clicking the same button. So its like when i click the new message: `Message 2 will appear` then when I click it again, `Message 3 will appear` so on and so forth.!

Comment: in case you use `hidemsg`  to hide divs, then use `$("#msg2.hidemsg")[0].removeClass("hidemsg")`. Also you can use `not()` and `:visible` selectors and take `[0]` item from collection

Comment: @teran can you explain it to me more? sorry i'm not that fond with js. tnx

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/n340ugdq/

Comment: `$(".hidemsg:not(:visible):first").toggle(); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but try below mentioned `code`

Use below mentioned HTML code:

```
<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggler();">New Message</a>
```

Use below mentioned javascript code:

```
var x=1;
function toggler() {
   var hidemsgLength=$('.hidemsg').length; 
   if(x<hidemsgLength){
      $('.hidemsg').eq(x).show();
      x++;
   }
}
```

Now coming to the css Part:

```
.hidemsg{display:none;}
.hidemsg:first-child{display:block;}
```

Comment: It works but the toggle hides the previous div, i want the new div to be shown below the previous div as well.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect now. This is jut what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it might be better to use unique IDs on div.

For multiple elements, prefer class.

Teran's solution is :

- on load, all divs are displayed
- on first click, first div is hidden
- on second click, second div is hidden
- ...

It means you can use`$(".my_class:visible").first().toggle();`

Comment: Thanks for this as well, it will greatly help me in my learning of js basics. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an *ID* can only be used *once*.

What you can do, if I understand your question correctly, is first hide all messages and display the first.

Then, when the user clicks the button, display the second, then the 3th, etc. 
I am not fond of an inline click handler, so i added an `eventListener` in JS.

```
// reference to button
var btn = document.querySelector('.js-button');

// which message to display
var index = 1;

// total number of messages
var numMessages = $('.hidemsg').length;

// hide 'm all
$('.hidemsg').hide();

// and toggle the first
toggler();

// when user clicks button, toggle the next one
btn.addEventListener('click', toggler);

function toggler() {
    $('.hidemsg').hide();   
    $('#msg' + index).show();

        // go to 1 again when the end is reached
    index = (index + 1 <= numMessages) ? index + 1 : 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j32yjsaw/1/

Answer (score 1):

I used a lot of comments to help you see exactly what was going on in the function. But basically, I'm keeping track of which `div` should be displayed by using a `data-` attribute in the `toggle` anchor.

```js
//Set up the click event listener
$('#toggler').on('click', function () {
  
  //Get the 'count' data property from the anchor tag
  var counter = $(this).data('count');
  
  //assign that to be the ID of the message you want to display
  var nextMessage = '#msg' + counter;
  
  $(nextMessage).show(); //Show that Message
  
  counter += 1; //increment counter (for next click)
  $(this).data('count', counter); //assign new counter var to #toggler
});
```

```css
.hidemsg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-count="2" id="toggler" type="button" class="btn btn-default">New Message</a>
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 2:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment2" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg3" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 3:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment3" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg4" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 4:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment4" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg5" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 5:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment5" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your div's have the same id. If you change the id's so that they are unique, with and increasing trailing value (msg1, msg2, ...), the function can be changed to something like this:

```
    var counter = 1;
    function toggler(divId) {
         $('#' + divId + counter).toggle();
    counter++;
    }
```

Comment: what if counter becomes 6, when there are 5 messages?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to keep it short and sweet, where you think about clicked element and the next element. Let me know if that works for you. Good luck!

```js
$(function() {

  $('.js-button').click(function() {
    if ($('div.active').next().hasClass('hidemsg')) {
      $('div.active').next('div').addClass('active').end().removeClass('active');
    }else{
      alert('Sorry, there is no next message');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.hidemsg {
  display: none;
}

.hidemsg.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg1" class="hidemsg active">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 2:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment2" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg2" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 3:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment3" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg3" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 4:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment4" placeholder="New message." />
</div>
<div id="msg4" class="hidemsg">
  <label for="commentcont" class="control-label">Message 5:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment5" placeholder="New message." />
</div>

<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default js-button">New Message</a>
```